# Cypher size() is slow - using huge database

Tags: database, performance, optimization, redis, cypher

I'm using redisgraph.
How do I fasten the count, since I need to filter `:a` by the count of `:c` in a database that have millions of nodes.

`size((:a)-[:r1]->(:b)<-[:r2]-(:c))`

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
MATCH (a:a) 
WITH a 
MATCH (a)-[:r1]->(:b)<-[:r2]-(c:c) 
WITH a, count(distinct(c)) as cnt
WHERE cnt >= 100
RETURN a, cnt
```